# Allow only specified email addresses to submit a form with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I'm creating a webpage that should only be accessible to people using `@example.com` or `@subdomain.example.com` The `public_html` folder has an `index.php` page and then the rest of the content is in `example.com/content` so ideally the `/content` subdirectory shouldn't be accessible.

Here's the HTML for the login page;

```html
<form action="./login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your work email address." name="email" required=""><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the PHP for `login.php` is;

```
  <?php

    $email = 'email@subdomain.example.com';

    $domains = array('example.com', 'subdomain.example.com');

    $pattern = "/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]*(" . implode('|', $domains) . ")$/i";

    if (preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
        echo '<script>
           window.location = "http://example.com/content/"
      </script>';
    } else {
        echo 'This is not a valid Company email address. Please go back and try again.';
    }
    ?>

<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$text = "Email: ".$email." At: ".$timestamp."\n";
$file = fopen("./users.txt","a+ \n");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

The idea is that people in the company will be able to log in but only if their email address matches a list so I'd specify that `steve@example.com`, `igor@example.com` and `jon@example.com` would all be able to log in. Only predetermined emails should be granted access. If the email is valid for both before the `@` and after the `@example.com` the user should be redirected to `example.com/content` and not be able to access `example.com/content` until they've entered their email address. I'd also have something stored so that `jon2018@example.com` would be `jon2018@example.com = Jon` so that a welcome message of `Hi, Jon` could be printed on the page.

The list of people and the times they log on is saved to a `.txt` file. I just need to figure out why;

`1` Anyone can currently log in regardless of input into the text box.

`2` How to limit log in to only predetermined email addresses & verify that they're valid email addresses.

`3` Store the allowed email addresses and names for the `Hi` message, although this can be skipped over.

`4` make sure that `/content` is inaccessible until someone has logged in (ideally a message then a redirect to the log in page).

I know that I could also implement passwords but I don't have the capacity or knowledge on how to do this so any assistance with the email method I've chosen would be greatly appreciated. I hope I've explained this in enough detail.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

`UPDATE 1`

```
$users = array("jon@example.com", "igor@example.com", "steve@example.com");
if(($users = $users === TRUE){
header("Location: http://example.com/content/");
}else{
die('This is not a valid Company email address. Please go back and try again.');
}
```

If I were to just authenticate users based on email and not associate with names (ie; skip out the welcome message) how would that work similar to the snippet above (incl subdomains). I just can't go using SQL because it's too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with Sessions, you can check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

You can redirect to a page without javascript so, instead of:

```
echo '<script>
window.location = "http://example.com/content/"
</script>';
```

use

```
header("Location: http://example.com/content/");
```

---

First you need something like an array or database where the emails that are allowed, 
   are stored. I would recommend a database with ID,FullName,E-Mail. Then you can simple do a sql query to the database with the email, if it returns true redirect, if not then don't. Example: (Establish a Connection first(google will help) then do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$email;";
if(($result = $dbConnection->query($sql)) === TRUE){
header("Location: http://example.com/content/");
}else{
//use die instead of echo
die('This is not a valid Company email address. Please go back and try again.');
}
```

And if you wan't to make the page only accessible, if an valid email has been entered. You can basicly do the same. After the submit button got clicked store the E-Mail entered in the textbox , do like so:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

And on the `http://example.com/content/` page. You check if the email is allowed to access this page. So:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$_SESSION['email']";
if($dbConnection->query($sql) != TRUE){
die("Not allowed to access this page, please enter an email at the Main Page");
//or simply redirect to the mainpage with header();
}else{
//show whatever you want to show
}
```

All you have to do to use $_SESSION is to include **session_start();** at the top of every php page! (it has to be started before an output is made, so basicly the first line of your file)

For the "Hi, Jon" Message, simply do a select or use the one above where you redirect to the other page and save the name to a $_SESSION variable like so :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$email;";
if(($result = $dbConnection->query($sql)) === TRUE){
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['Name'] = $data['FullName'];
header("Location: http://example.com/content/");
}else{
//use die instead of echo
die('This is not a valid Company email address. Please go back and try 
again.');
}
```

At `http://example.com/content/` you then can use `$_SESSION['Name']` to access the variable. Only if you used `session_start();` at the beginning of the file!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the time spent answering me but I honestly don't know how to do any of this.

Comment: Something without SQL would be useful. Like an array for the first half of the email that then has a name attached to it. The welcome message isn't compulsory. I just need the email validation from a set list of emails and the rest of the contents of the site hidden until then.

Comment: I've added another snippet at the bottom of the question. Something in an array format would be easier. I'll do without the welcome message. I just want to only redirect if the email is stored and if they're not logged in, send them to the main page.

Comment: You will have to compare the entered email to every value in the array. I'm not sure on how to do that with php, just Google that it should be something like `for($i = 0; $array.length > i; i++) { //comparsion code here}`

Comment: Couldn't you just compare the entire thing as a string or create all of the emails as separate variables?

Comment: $_SESSION is what you need to use for the 'login' thing.  It can be an array aswell, then you gotta loop trought it again, just like the email validation on login. I can only give you hints, if you don't understand something i tell you, i'll be glad to explain. But google most likely will give you the best answers!

Comment: Sure you can, but as a programmer actually.. less code > more code. You can store steve@example.com to $steve, then use if or switch case with every variable.